# Set zoom level to display full extent of specific layer when starting a project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, scale, zoom

I have project in QGIS 3.2 with different shapefiles and WMS layer. When I start the projectfile (.qgs) I want the extent of the map to be the same as one specific WMS layer (same as the option "zoom to layer" in QGIS).

I created the following macro, where I get the right scale of the layer but the extent is not adjusted to the specific layer.

```
def openProject():
    from qgis.utils import iface
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(4096000)
```

Is there an macro or even an option in QGIS to accomplish this?

Comment: Basic option: before saving the project, zoom to that layers extent & location.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the extent manually everytime before closing the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use macros. Just edit `openProject` method in " Project > Project Properties > Macros" like that:

```
def openProject():
    from qgis.core import QgsProject
    from qgis.utils import iface
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

    # change LAYERNAME into your WMS layer name
    # I assume WMS layer has unique name, no more layers with same name
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LAYERNAME')[0]
    canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
    canvas.refresh()
```

You also have to change "Enable Macros" option into "Always (not recommended)" or "For this session only" in "Settings > Options > General". Or you can just click "Enable Macros" text shown on starting a project which contains macros.